# Formalising arguments in propositional logic

Tags: logic

I'm trying to figure out how to turn this into propositional logic:

> If God does not exist, then it is not true that, if I pray, my prayers
> will be answered.
>
> I do not pray.
> Therefore, God exists.

I need to formalise it in propositional logic and do a systematic truth table evaluation.
My idea was:

- "G" stands for God exists
- "P" I pray
- "A" answered

In my opinion it would be this in propositional logic:

¬G → ¬(P → A)  =  ¬P → G

... but suddenly that doesn't work.
May anyone got an idea what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your formalization is wrong: you have forgotten the "it is not true that---" clause.

Comment: @toxicshark: Ok after your edit your translation is correct, but what you wrote after the "=" makes no sense. I have no idea what you mean by "does not work". Just make the truth-table for all possible truth-value combinations for G,P,A and conclude from there.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You're right, it was a typing mistake. I've forgot to add a negation. Sorry for that!

Comment: "If God does not exist, then it is not true that, if I pray, my prayers will be answered." is $\lnot G \to \lnot (P \to A)$. The proof is by contra: assume $\lnot G$; then by MP: $\lnot (P \to A)$. But $\lnot P$. Thus, from tautology: $\lnot P \to (P \to A)$, we have by MP: $P \to A$. Now we have a contradiction, and thus $G$.

Comment: Having said that, you have not proved $G$, but only that from G→¬(P→A) and ¬P, it folllows $G$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: You're missing a "¬" in front of "G".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @MauroALLEGRANZA and user21820 ! I really appreciate it. So ¬G→(¬(P→A) and ¬P) denotes the last 2 sentences "I do not pray. Therefore, God exists"?

Comment: $\lnot P$ is "I do not pray" and $G$ is "God exists", as per your post.